Restrict CPU core usage on linux in python program using Piper TTS library
For some reason when I'm using PiperTTS to generate speech using taskset -c 2,3 python myprogram.py the system does not restrict processing to the cores I specify.
When I use another library, such as llama-cpp-python, taskset is able to restrict the cores execution occurs on. I also tried using psutil python library to set CPU affinity, but this did not work either.

How or why one python program would be able to bypass restrictions set by taskset?
Why Piper TTS library isn't using cores set by taskset?


PiperTTS leverages OnnxRuntime, which internally manages its own threads.
Try using the -a (--all-tasks, "Set or retrieve the CPU affinity of all the tasks (threads) for a given PID") flag with taskset (e.g., taskset -ac 2,3 ...) or configure OnnxRuntime as follows:
import onnxruntime as ort

sess_opt = ort.SessionOptions()
sess_opt.intra_op_num_threads = 3
sess_opt.add_session_config_entry('session.intra_op_thread_affinities', '1;2')

sess = ort.InferenceSession('model.onnx', sess_opt, ...)


# initialize Piper
# see https://github.com/rhasspy/piper/blob/c0670df63daf07070c9be36b5c4bed270ad72383/src/python_run/piper/voice.py#L25

from piper import PiperVoice
from piper.config import PiperConfig

voice = PiperVoice(
    config=PiperConfig.from_dict({...}),
    session=sess
)



using --all-tasks did not work, but creating onnxruntime session and passing that into piper did! Also good to know about onnxruntime session configurations when using piper generally. Thanks mate

@ekcrisp, glad to hear it! Just wondering, have you tried using numactl as @bua suggeste? onnxruntime is "NUMA-aware" and numactl should work well for your task.

I spoke too soon, numactl works but I'd like to set core usage in my python code. The issue is that the "intra_op_thread_affinities" set the cores used by the "intra-op threads" but not the main thread which is coordinating the parallelism. From what I can tell in the docs, there is no configuration in the onnxruntime session options that lets you choose the cpu core for the main thread. Do you know if this is true?

taskset works on 'best-effort' basis, OS doesn't necessarily mandate desired restrictions.
Use numactl -c instead, this work in conjunction with OS, so if core's you try to use are restricted, numactl will fail to execute (where taskset would still run, allowing your procces to run with no restriction).
numactl is much better practice, i'd advice to retire using taskset.
Have a look at cgroups as well.
